# How do you hide elements within a bootstrap navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This seems like a pretty standard thing to need to do, but I haven't been able to make it work.  I want a login form in my navbar, and then be able to hide the user/pass fields when a user clicks the login button.  I haven't been able to hide any elements, they just immediately re-appear again.  I have tried using JQuery's hide() method, and adding the 'hidden' class to the element.  In at least Chrome, it flickers and the element remains.  Here is a simple demo to illustrate this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Demo</title>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div id="remove_me" class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button id='the_button' class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

  <script>
    $('#the_button').click(function() {
      $('#remove_me').addClass('hidden');
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is page is getting refreshed when you click on the submit button, because it is sending the form. That's why input field is getting visible again.

You can use preventDefault to avoid sending the form and make ajax call for the form.

```
<script>
$('#the_button').click(function(e) {
    $('#remove_me').addClass('hidden');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  Since the button wasn't of the 'submit' class I didn't think it could be submitting the form.  This worked though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script.

```
<script>
$('#the_button').click(function() {
  $('#remove_me').hide();
});
</script>
```

or this.

```
<script>
$('#the_button').click(function() {
  $('#remove_me').css("display", "none");
});
</script>
```